Let $\varphi: K_1 \rightarrow K_2$ be a ring homomorphism. Also, let $M$ be $K_2$-module.
Let $\varphi: K_1 \rightarrow K_2$ be a ring homomorphism. Also, let $M$ be $K_2$-module.
a) Show: $M$ becomes left $K_1$-module for $•: K \times M \ \rightarrow M,(a,m) \mapsto\varphi(a)\cdot m$.
b) Let $\varphi$ be an epimorphism. Show: if $M$ is simple $K_2$-module, then $M$ is simple $K_1$-module.
My attempt: For a) I took $a,b\in K_1,x,y\in M$:

$a•(x+y)=\varphi(a)\cdot(x+y)=\varphi(a)\cdot x+\varphi(a)\cdot y=a•x+a•y$,
$(a+b)•x=\varphi(a+b)\cdot x=(\varphi(a)+\varphi(b))\cdot x=\varphi(a)\cdot x+ \varphi(b)\cdot x=a•x+b•x$ and
$a•(b•x)=a•(\varphi(b)\cdot x)=\varphi(a)(\varphi(b)\cdot x)=\varphi(ab)\cdot x=(ab)•x$.

Thus $M$ is left $K_1$-module. Is my explanation well-written or are there any mistakes or something missing in order to prove this?
For b) I took simple $K_2$-module $M$. Then $K_2M\neq \{0\}$ and $\{0\}$,$M$ are only $K_2$-submodules of $M$. Now I took submodule $N\neq \{0\}$ of $K_1$-module $M$. Now I want to show: $N=M$. Here I was lost. I only observe that since $\varphi$ is an epimorphism, $Im \varphi=K_2$, so for every $y\in K_2$, there exists $x\in K_1$, such that $\varphi(x)=y$.

Note that if $M$ is a simple $K_2$-module, it is of the form $M = K_2 .a \cong K_2/I$ (where $I = {\rm ann}(a) \subset K_2$) (for some element $a \in M$).  But $K_2 \cong K_1/{\rm ker}(\phi)$, and so the ideal $I \subset K_2$ corresponds to an ideal $J \subset K_1$ that contains ${\rm ker}(\phi)$. Thus $M \cong K_1/J$ is a simple $K_1$-module.

@Matthew There is a one-one correspondence between the ideals of $R/I$ and the ideals of $R$ containing $I$ (where $R$ is a ring and $I \subset R$ an ideal (this is a standard result in basic ring theory). Yes, I have used this result.

Since there is no non-trivial ideal in $K_2/I$, it follows that there is no non-trivial ideal in $K_1/J$ and hence $M$ is simple as a $K_1$-module.

You can look up any basic text on algebra for the proof.
